# When to expect a direct sub-object access on a loaded instance?

Tags: entity-framework-core

Up front, I do not mean Lazy loading, but simply navigation.

I simply want to ask for an persistent object containing an other persistent object I want for example print the name of.

The class hierarchy is implementing an forward reference to the sub object, so the framework should find it's way to the other table and get the instance there.

Was running the not successful test on beta6.

**Update based on comment:**

```
Public Class Class1

    Public Id as Integer
    Public Name as String
    Public Detail as Details

End Class

Public Class Details

    Public Id as Integer
    Public Parent as Class1
    Public Offer as Single
    Public Need as Single

End Class
```

I simply want to load instances of `Class1`, then navigate from an instance directly to the `Details` object. I know Lazy Loading is not yet implemented. (what would be an fine extension) But I am expecting an OR Mapper should AT LEAST directly answer the loaded Objects in the declared hierarchy!

Comment: Can you update your question with a code example? It is not clear to me from your question what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Public Class Class1
 Public Id as Integer
 Public Name as String
 ...
 Public Detail as Details
End Class

Public Class Details
 Public Id as Integer
 Public Parent as Class1
 Public Offer as Single
 ...
 Public Need as Single
End Class

Simply whant ot load instances of Class1 
Then navigating from such an instance directly to the former Stored Details
I was Told allready Lazy Loading is not yet implemented (what would be an fine extension)
But i am expecting an OR Mapper should AT LEAST directly answer the loaded Objects in the declared hierarchy!

Comment: Add the code to the actual question itself. Click the edit link on the bottom left of the question.